# fb.xd.resolverelation(...).fb' is null or not an object Driving me crazy

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, xfbml

I have ben trying for hours to get this working... In some IE browsers NOTE not all i get this error when trying to connect with Facebook login.

```
fb.xd.resolverelation(...).fb' is null or not an object
```

The error appears when the script inside the pop up box is going back to my site after login at Facebook.

My code looks like this for connecting

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '12345',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
            channelUrl : '//site.com/pages/channel.php',
          });

      function updateButton(response) {
                     //button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                     loginHolder = document.getElementById('faceAccess');



                     if (response.authResponse) {
                         //user is already logged in and connected
                         loginHolder.style.display = "none";
                         FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                             login(response, info);
                         });

                     } 
                 }

      //window.onload=function(){
          // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
          FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
      //}

    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `status     : true,` to `status     : false,` and see if that provides better results.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That didn't do it however :( I never had any problems with this before I can't seem to understand the problem...

Comment: next try forcing it to use HTTPS only.  See if that one version of IE likes that better.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, sadly that didn't do it either :( Could it have something to do with cross domain? Its so strange it just happens to some browsers

Comment: Do you have a p3p http header?

Comment: Just added them but that didn't change the result

Comment: Good luck, I'm out of options. At least we got the p3p issue resolved as that would have stopped IE 7,8,9 from being able to do login auth correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying!! Maybe ill just have to live with it in some browsers...